# how do i return the number of elements in the array in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

Im trying to return the number of items in an array list but its not working

this is my code:

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int {

    val list = ArrayList<String>()
    val ref = dbSavedStories.child(currentUid!!)

    ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (childSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                val key = childSnapshot.key
                list.add(key.toString())
            }

            println(list.count())
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    })

    return list.count()
}
```

on the line that has: "println(list.count())" prints the correct number which is 5

but when i try and return the number it returns 0

how do i fix this?

Comment: You've added a listener that _will_ print `list.count()` whenever there is a data change, but you don't wait for a data change to fill the list.  So the `onDataChange` function hasn't been called by the time you `return list.count()`

Comment: how do i fix it?

Comment: Probably the best way is to explicitly populate list in the method.  Get a snapshot from `ref` to start with.

Comment: In current way you can't, either accept a lambda which accept the Int and returns Unit, which will be called inside `onDataChange`. Or use [suspendCancellableCoroutine](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html) to return a result from the function, note that this requires function to be suspendable (if you don't have access to mark function suspend, as you seem to override it, only method is callback as described as first option).

Comment: I still haven't managed to fix this, if someone can post an example of how to fix it i would be very grateful cause i am struggling to fix it. thank you